# Global variable is interfering with other code I would like to put it into these functions as a local variable of make it all into 1 big function

Tags: javascript

I have A global scope variable that is interfering with the rest of my code I want to be able to implement it within these 3 functions or to turn it all into 1 function that doesn't use global variables but I'm not sure how to achieve this can someone help me. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<!-- slideshow-container -->
<div class="dot-container-for-slide-banner">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just put the whole code here inside an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (short IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), that should prevent any unnecessary global variables:

```
(() => {
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  // ...
})();
```

You should also absolutely avoid inline attribute handlers like

```
onclick="plusSlides(-1)"
```

and

```
onclick="currentSlide(1)"
```

because they [require global pollution and have a demented scope chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). Attach the listeners properly using `addEventListener` instead:

```
document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => {
  plusSlides(-1);
});
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', () => {
  plusSlides(1);
});

document.querySelectorAll('.dot').forEach((span, i) => {
  span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentSlide(i + 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working I added the HTML above

Comment: The original code works that global variable is just interfering with another piece of code that's for something else

Comment: Remove the inline handlers from the HTML, they're [quite bad practice and require global pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045)